# In php: how to pass the $conn (mysqli) object between functions in the same class?

Tags: php, mysqli

I do have the following piece of php code I'm writting:

```
public $conn;

public function start(){
    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbName);
    if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
    }


}

public function sql($q){

    $res=  $this->conn->query($q);  
    echo $res;
    return $res;    
}
```

The following code gives error when used as I create an object of the db class.

How can I do to pass the $conn object between the function start and the function sql properly?

Thanks

Comment: What error does it give you? Do you actually call the start functino of your object?

Comment: publish the whole class

Comment: from what I can tell if you name `start()` as `__construct()` you should be fine.

Comment: You should make $conn private or protected, but not public e.g. `private $conn;`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's a DB connection wrapper, I would change the function start to the class constructor:

```
class DbWrapper {
    public $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbName);
        if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $this->conn->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public function sql($q) {
        $res = $this->conn->query($q);  
        //echo $res; /* echo doesn't print object */
        return $res;    
    }
}

$db = new DbWrapper();
$db->sql('SELECT ...');
```

Comment: @xly0n post your whole class

Answer (score 0):

When you call `sql()`, first line should be `start()` because you need to initialize the `$conn` variable first which is in `start()` function. Now on page refresh and such you lose that so you should call it from your `sql` function.

```
public function sql($q){
    $this->start();
    $res=  $this->conn->query($q);  
    echo $res;
    return $res;    
}
```

Your `$conn` variable is not initialized if you call sql function directly.

Comment: That way he's always creating a new connection, and it should be `$this->start();`

Comment: Yes but that is the only code he has provided so I am going off the sample in OP. @claudio